# Can someone please tell me what is wrong with my code?

Tags: c++, pointers, bad-alloc

I want to manipulate a pointer to an array of structs by adding values to the array and printing them.
This is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct words {
    char letter;
    bool marked;
};

int main(){
    int ncols, nrows;
    words* data;
    data = new words [ncols * nrows];
    cout << "Insert ncols : ";
    cin >> ncols;
    cout << "Insert nrows : ";
    cin >> nrows;
    data[0].letter = 'a';
    data[1].letter = 'b';
    data[2].letter = 'c';
    data[3].letter = 'd';

    for(int i = 0; i < (ncols*nrows); i++){
        cout << (data+i)->letter << endl;
    }

}
```

I'm getting this error message:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc'
  what():  std::bad_alloc
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You seem to assume, the compiler would know your intentions and delays the line `data = new words [ncols * nrows];` until after you entered the respective values.

Comment: you need to initialize `data = new words [ncols * nrows];` after initializing `ncols` and `nrows`

Comment: do not ignore compiler warnings! With the right options compilers refuse to compile your code https://godbolt.org/z/4xj9f6

Comment: Not initializing `ncols` and `nrows` and thus causing UB?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple error. You used the `nrows` and`ncols` variables before they had any value. Obviously you should only use a variable after it has been given a value.

Change your code like this

```
cout << "Insert ncols : ";
cin >> ncols;
cout << "Insert nrows : ";
cin >> nrows;
data = new words [ncols * nrows];
```

Answer (score 4):

```
int ncols, nrows;
words* data;
data = new words [ncols * nrows];
```

This is undefined behaviour. Your `ncols` and `nrows` are *uninitialised*. Later on you do:

```
cout << "Insert ncols : ";
cin >> ncols;
cout << "Insert nrows : ";
cin >> nrows;
```

which **does** initialise them, but you do that **after** you created your `data` array. Modification of `ncols` and `nrows` after the `new words [ncols * nrows]` line **will not change the size of that array**. Those values are not bound. They are used to create an array. One-time job.

To fix your issue, first initialise your variables and then use them.